# POI Excel HSSFPicture Image and Sizing

Tags: java, excel, groovy, apache-poi

I am adding an image to the worksheet through some code like this:

```
// Create the drawing patriarch.  This is the top level container for all shapes.
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

//add a picture shape
//ClientAnchor anchor = this.creationHelper.createClientAnchor();
ClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor((short)0, (short)0, (short)0, (short)0, (short)0, (short)0, (short)2, (short)5)

// 0 = Move and size with Cells, 2 = Move but don't size with cells, 3 = Don't move or size with cells. 
anchor.setAnchorType(2)

HSSFPicture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, this.images.get("logo"));
pict.resize() ;
```

However just after the images are added, I resize the columns - which seems to mess things up.  It resizes the images - which is not what I want.

```
//psuedo code
public void autoSizeColumns() {
    def cols = (StartColumn..this.cMax)
    cols.each { i ->
        sheet.autoSizeColumn i
    }   
}

BrandedWorksheet v; 
v.autoSizeColumns()
```

If I don't perform the   autoSizeColumns() the image is the proper size.

Is there any way to have both?

Comment: Could you perhaps not size the columns first, then add the image at the size you want?

Comment: reverse the order of adding the image and autoresize has no effect...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is crazy and doesn't make much sense, but allocating the proper amount of spacing and rows seems to be the key.  I added enough rows so that the image could be bound internally to the rows - and all seems good.

Moral of the story: keep working and messing about and it may eventually work.  You will get really frustrated, and there won't be a ton of help out there - because those of us who have properly sized an image don't really understand why.

Comment: It is correct. If you size the column below the image size, the image is stretched. If you have enough space, then it's perfect and image is not stretched. I'm assuming a factor of 40 for my column width calculations.